# Problems opening file from command line in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want my RCP Eclipse application to open files from the command line when given the filename as an argument, so the OS can associate the RCP with some extensions.

I found that the eclipse.ini file must specify the default action with

```
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
```

This is set in my .ini file, but when I call the executable followed by a filename, it doesn't open the file. Do I need something else? Some plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://www.sigasi.com/content/make-eclipse-open-files-command-line.

The executable name must be the same as the one set in the `appName` property in the plugin.xml of the RCP. Now it works.