# Eclipse segmentation fault with --launcher.openFile

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, segmentation-fault

I'm running [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) (with my own plugin in it) with `--launcher.openFile` option active:

```
/path/to/eclipse/eclipse -data /home/workspace --launcher.openFile myfile.ext
```

but, instead of opening the file, Eclipse crashes immediately (before showing the splash image) and writes "Segmentation fault" to the terminal.

Any idea of what could cause this problem or how to get a more meaningful error message?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in Eclipse due to relative path names.  I've analyzed what's going on.  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439459

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. I tried to debug the core dump with dbg, and here's what I found:

```
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0xb75e01a6 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xb773da12 in checkPath (path=0xbfe1b3bb "test.txt", programDir=0x0, reverseOrder=0) at ../eclipseCommon.c:532
#2  0xb7736b9e in parseArgs (pArgc=0xbfe19aa0, argv=0x99bb0f8) at ../eclipse.c:852
#3  0xb7735bcf in run (argc=5, argv=0x99bb0f8, vmArgs=0x0) at ../eclipse.c:407
#4  0x080490ee in main (argc=7, argv=0x99bb0f8) at ../eclipseMain.c:193
```

The only thing that seemed wrong to me was `programDir=0x0`, i.e., there's a pointer named programDir whose value is NULL. Then I tried to call my RCP passing the full path to the file, and it worked. Maybe it's the same with you.

I also noticed that if I supply another argument after the filename, the same error occurs.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler under Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: You're right. I ran:  eclipse -data /home/workspace --launcher.openFile /home/workdir/myfile.ext    and I didn't get a segmentation fault. However, Eclipse started without opening the file.

Comment: Be sure that your launcher name is the same as the appName property of the RCP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712827/problems-opening-file-from-command-line-in-eclipse You can add the argument `-name [AppName]` to make them match.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround for the bug, (using **realpath** command to provide absolute paths for the file(s) to open)

create a launcher script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/eclipse/eclipse --launcher.openFile $(realpath "$@")
```